# Ignoring timezones when creating a date in javascript/momentjs

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I am creating a schedule for something on the east coast, and I need to create a date that always returns a date object/timestamp for this time.

So, if I open the page in Paris at 18:00, the `"new myDate()"` should return 12:00.

Any suggestions on how I can do this with wither momentJS or just Javascript? The end result should be a javascript Date object.

Answer (score 151, accepted):

You can do this with moment.js using `moment.utc()`.

http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/utc/

```
moment([2011, 10, 8, 5]).format(); // different output based on timezone
moment.utc([2011, 10, 8, 5]).format(); // same output for all timezones
```

The way `moment.utc` works is by setting a flag internally to use `getUTCMinutes` instead of `getMinutes`, thus the output is the same in all timezones.

Comment: Ah, didn't see that one. How would you add the right timezone offset with this? I managed to do it with js, but I would prefere momentjs. I tried this: `new Date(moment.utc().add('minutes', -moment().zone()).unix() * 1000)`, but the date is 5 hours of.

Comment: You could fake it by just not using a timezone. So if the date needs to be at 5AM, just do moment.utc([year, month, date, 5]) and then format and display that. If you are trying to display a date in a specific timezone, it gets trickier, as you need to figure out the offset based on when DST happens for that timezone.

Comment: Experiment with moment.utc().zone(5) to let momentjs handle the time zone offset internally.

Comment: It won't work.

moment.utc('2014/09/05 12:00').format() will give you '2014-09-05T08:00:00+00:00' (depends on timezone)

moment('2014/09/05 12:00').format() will give you '2014-09-05T12:00:00+04:00' (timezone information included)

The best way to ignore timezone is to specify your own format:

moment('2014/09/05 12:00').format('YYYY-MM-DD[T]HH:mm:ss')

Comment: @RomanPushkin, it would be better for you to specify a parsing format during the call to `moment.utc`. `moment.utc('2014/09/05 12:00', 'YYYY/MM/DD HH:mm').format()`

Comment: @RomanPushkin see the warning at http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string/. Browser support for parsing a string is inconsistent, so adding a format allows moment to figure out what numbers go where in the call to `Date.utc(year, month, date, etc)`

Comment: I've played with a few other date parsers out here and the moment approach is the most straight forward.  I would highly recommend using this approach as a solution.

Answer (score 18):

If you want your timezone completely ignored, you can use the following approach:

```
  var firstDayStr = '29 January 2014';
  var startAtTime = '10:01:02 AM';
  var localFormat = 'YYYY-MM-DD[T]HH:mm:ss';

  var m = moment(firstDayStr + ' ' + startAtTime).format(localFormat);

  console.log(m);
```

Output:

```
2014-01-29T10:01:02
```

Comment: @M98 give it a try, it should work. Just pass as argument to moment(...)