# jQuery date time conversion

Tags: jquery, date, time

I have a date in this format:

```
2015-06-06T23:02:21+0000
```

and I need to convert it into something like this:

```
06 Juin 2015,23:02
```

How do I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Try with [jQuery dateFormat](https://github.com/phstc/jquery-dateFormat)

or use jQuery UI

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('span.date').each(function() { 
        var dateFormat = $(this).text()
        var dateFormat = $.datepicker.formatDate('MM dd, yy', new Date(dateFormat));
        //alert(dateFormat);
        $(this).html(dateFormat + "<br>");
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/adamculpepper/rHXcp/

Comment: am not using jquery ui and getting datepicker is not defined

Comment: You can download it from https://jqueryui.com/download/all/  and include this in your file

Comment: Thanks a lot man but what about the time? Should i do it like this : formatDate('MM dd, yy hh mm', new Date(dateFormat));

Comment: For time  you have to add timepicker plugin...Try this https://plugins.jquery.com/datetimepicker/

Comment: Am not using timepicker anywhere in my script! anyway thanks for helping so far.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose 'a' was the time which need to be converted,i.e:

```
var a = 2015-06-06T23:02:21+0000;
var b = a.split('T');
var c = (b[1].substring(0,5));
var a = $.datepicker.formatDate('dd MM yy,', new Date(a));
var time = a+c;
return time;
```

where  in this case time = 06 June 2015, 23:02

Answer (score 0):

For parsing and formatting dates/times, [Moment.js](http://momentjs.com/) is probably your best option.

```
moment.locale("fr");
var value = moment.utc("2015-06-06T23:02:21+0000", moment.ISO_8601);
var displayValue = value.format("DD MMMM YYYY,HH:mm");
```

**NB:** You need to use the `moment.utc(...)` function to avoid converting the date to your local time-zone, as documented in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13315755/124386).