# Display same time irrespective of any timezone using Moment.js

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I wanted to display same time irrespective of any time zone.

I have a shift defined for 7AM to 7PM its converting to user browser time zone using Moment.JS.

```
this.set("ShiftDetails", moment(this.get("11/22/2017 7:00:00 AM")).format('HH:mm'));

this.set("ShiftDetails1", moment(this.get("11/22/2017 19:00:00 AM")).format('HH:mm'));
```

This is getting converted to user browser specific zone .If the user browser zone in IST its convert the time from IST to UTC and displays.

I need to display same time regardless of the user's time zone. Please Help!!!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Ignoring timezones when creating a date in javascript/momentjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13315325/ignoring-timezones-when-creating-a-date-in-javascript-momentjs)

Comment: "the same time" ... well 07:00 UTC is the same time as 12:30 IST ... or did you want your thing to display 07:00 regardless of users timezone? you'll need to do some maths

Comment: Yes i wanted to display 7 as it it.Because the time zone can be different .

Comment: did you find any solution for this? I am facing a similar issue now.

Comment: is `19:00:00 AM` even a valid time? Generally when the meridiem is also specified the time ranges from `00:00:00 AM` to `11:59:59 AM`.